# How can I insert a block code inside a php page?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have this front-page.php page in my site and I want to put a block code directly in the php page. So I got a div and I want to put it in there. But the code is like

```
<!-- wp:latest-posts {"postsToShow":3,"displayPostContent":true,"excerptLength":30,"displayPostDate":true,"postLayout":"grid","displayFeaturedImage":true,"featuredImageSizeSlug":"large","align":"wide","className":"tw-mt-8 tw-img-ratio-3-2 tw-stretched-link is-style-default"} /-->
```

It's from  a widget. I coudn't make it work please help :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can insert block code into any php template by using the function [`do_blocks()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_blocks/) and passing in (valid) block content as a string, eg:

```
    <?php

    $block_content = '<!-- wp:latest-posts {"postsToShow":3,"displayPostContent":true,"excerptLength":30,"displayPostDate":true,"postLayout":"grid","displayFeaturedImage":true,"featuredImageSizeSlug":"large","align":"wide","className":"tw-mt-8 tw-img-ratio-3-2 tw-stretched-link is-style-default"} /-->';
    
    echo do_blocks($block_content);

    ?>
```

Comment: uhh thank you so much it worked perfectly ;)

Comment: Hi, I have a HTML block on my page which I need to embed in my custom page template, but its not working with this. It does not load the preview with HTTP ERROR 500.
`$block_content = '<!-- wp:html --><p>[gravityform id="3" title="false" description="true" ajax="true"]</p><!-- /wp:html -->'
echo do_blocks($block_content);`
Please help me if i'm doing anythibg wrong

Comment: @S.B. You might be better off directly using `do_shortcode` instead of putting the shortcode inside a block inside a php template: `echo do_shortcode([gravityform id="3" title="false" description="true" ajax="true"]);`